# ISCSI, MPIO and Target-IPs

Tags: iscsi, mpio

Today I played around with ISCSI, MPIO and performed some tests. Some went as expected, someothers delivered results I cannot explain.

The Test-Environment was 2 virtual machines, named `A` and `B`. Both VMs have been assigned with 2 NICS, let's call them `A-1`, `A-2`, `B-3` and `B-4`, to make it clear which Host was utilizing which IP Adresses.

I limited each Nic to 100 Mbps to have enough time to observe results.

On Host `B`, I created 2 virtual Disks, assigned them both to the same ISCSI-Target.

#### First Test: Single LU , Single Session

When I established the ISCSI Connection between `A` and `B` with a single session.

The result was as expected: about 12 MB/s Transfer Speed.

#### Second Test: Single LU , Two distinct Sessions

In this test, I created 2 ISCSI Sessions, namely (`A-1`, `B-3`) and (`A-2`, `B-4`)

The results were as expected:

- Regular Transfer showed around 24 MB/s
- Disabling any of the NICs during transfer on any device lowered the transferspeed to 12 MB/s again, while every vm only utilizes one nic for the remaining file part.

#### Third Test: Single LU , Four Sessions (Full Join)

After creating the sessions (`A-1`, `B-3`), (`A-1`, `B-4`), (`A-2`, `B-3`) and (`A-2`, `B-4`), the result was as expected:

- Regular Transfer showed around 24 MB/s
- Disabling any of the SENDING nics, leads to 100 Mbps on the remaining nic, and 50 Mbps on each receiving nic. -> 12 MB/s
- Disabling any of the RECEIVING nics, leads to 100 Mbps on the remaining nic, and 50 MBps on each sending nic. -> 12 MB/s

#### Fourth Test: Two LU (same ISCSI-Target), Four Sessions (Full Join)

This is the test that failed - even before I could start to test the fail-over Szenarios.

- Distinct File Transfer to any disk worked as expected. (200 Mbps)
- However, when I initiated another Transfer to the SECOND LU, while the first Transfer was running - the first Transfer dropped to 0 Mbps until the second Transfer finished... ?

Is this by design, cause the session cannot hold 2 different conversations - or is this just some "strange" effect of running everything virtualized on the same Hyper-V host?

---

The Initiator:

[image]

The Target:

[image]

The Mentioned "copy-problem" with 2 concurrent Transfers (Screenshot was made with nics @ 200 Mbps - thought maybe 100 is just to Little for the tests):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should the iSCSI target on the host, not the VM.

Why ? because by dooing so you scrap all the bonus the host give, like that;

If you are using Microsoft's iSCSI initiator within the virtual machine, you cannot perform snapshot operations on the virtual machine because it is not supported. For more information, see Running a Third-Party iSCSI initiator in the Virtual Machine in the SAN System Design and Deployment Guide for your version of ESX. (https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009073)

or if you use vReplicator, it would be a problem (if you want to get the data outside of the san)

Edited: too long for a comment

Comment: Running everything virtualized was just for testing purpose. For production purpose every Vnic, Vswitch and VServer will be a physical one. However I'm not using ESX, but Hyperv.

Comment: @dognose Same fact apply on hyperv for the snapshot, but if for testing its all right!

Comment: I'm aware of this. But this was just a "lab" Setup. But thanks for pointing this out anyway.